# How to redirect stderr output (using fprintf )to a log file?

Tags: c, file, logging, stderr, io-redirection

I am doing some debugging and would like to redirect standard error message to a file; so, it can view inside a debug log file.
I do need it be done from C-code, not by the UNIX shell redirection.

I need to debug some of the such modules.
I have a set of debuging-tools that writes to strerr(console). It is easy included into a source and present set of comfortable macro and function to be used for debuging a source.

Below are codes from a header file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOGWRAPPER(tag, fmt, args...) \
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: " fmt "\n", tag, ##args)   

#define LOG_DEBUG(...) LOGWRAPPER(__VA_ARGS__)

...

...

#define LOG_DEBUG(tag, fmt, args...)                 \
  do {                                               \
    (true) ? ALOG(LOG_DEBUG, tag, fmt, ##args)       \
           : fprintf(stderr, "%s" fmt, tag, ##args); \
  } while (0)
....
```

eventually all printing will come back to here which is the header file. So I guess I have to make some changes over

```
#define LOGWRAPPER(tag, fmt, args...) \
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: " fmt "\n", tag, ##args)
```

Any idea? Or shall I create a file path and insert in the fprintf?

Comment: If you're using macros for logging, add `__func__`, `__FILE__`, and `__LINE__` to the logged data so it's immediately apparent where it came from.  And that macro has a problem - it will fail to compile for any format string that isn't a string literal.

Comment: i sure did use  __func__, __FILE__, and __LINE__ inside my message line. Take note: eventually all print related function will call back to this header file. Things that I don't understand now is how to redirect the stderr output to a file/

Comment: `__func__`, `__FILE__`, and `__LINE__` should be built into the macro so the caller doesn't have to repeatedly enter them.

Answer (score 3):

A typical way to redirect `stderr` in C code is to use `dup2()` to (essentially) map the file descriptor to a new file. For example, something like:

int f = open ("mylog.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND,  0644);
dup2 (f, STDERR_FILENO);

There are other ways -- you could use `freopen()` on `stderr`, for example.

But...

If you're doing all logging using a macro you defined, why not simply define the macro to do something completely different? That is, define `LOG_DEBUG` to call a function you supply, and not `fprintf()` at all?

I'm sure there are other opinions on this, but I don't like to use `stderr` for routine logging. I only want `stderr` to get serious, program-breaking error messages. It's possible (maybe) that your code is not the only code that might write to `stderr` -- libraries might do so as well. It might be appropriate for their output to be collected up and sent to a general debug log but, then again, it might not. I always do general logging using functions specifically for that purpose.

Comment: can you show example on how to use the freopen() on stderr? I'm sure that 
#define LOGWRAPPER(tag, fmt, args...) \
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: " fmt "\n", tag, ##args)
is the only thing that I allow to ,ale changes

Comment: `freopen ("mylog.txt", "a+", stderr);` But it doesn't really make any difference -- changing how `stderr` is handled changes it for everything that writes to `stderr`, however it does it.

Answer (score 0):

> I do need it be done from C-code, not by the UNIX shell redirection.

Understanding how the shell implements redirection will give you the neccesary insight on how to do it in your own program.

POSIX defines three standard file descriptors that are available at the start of each process: 0 = stdin, 1 = stdout, 2 = stderr

The C standard library defines also three `FILE*` streams *exposed through globally available symbols*, that are named `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` and directly correspond to the numeric file descriptors; the POSIX standard defines an additional function operating on `FILE*` streams called [`fileno`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno).

At the end of the day, everything boils down to file descriptors.

Although it is possible to `freopen` an existing stream, to a new destination, that will usually result in a new, different file descriptor. While the `FILE*` stream you reponed (possibly through a global symbol like `stderr`) will then go to that new location, it will not affect parts of the program, that bypass the C standard library functions. *Hence the recommended way is to replace the filedescriptor itself*, which is what the syscall [`dup2`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) does.

With `dup2` you can take an existing file descriptor and duplicate-overwrite it over another existing file descriptor. So if you open a log file, and duplicate it over file descriptor 2 (=stderr) its output gets redirected there.

This is how shells redirect, and you can use it in your program, too:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* replace fd=2, i.e. stderr, with a file of our choosing: */
    int fd_logfile = open("logfile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0644);
    if( 0 <= fd_logfile ){
        dup2(fd_logfile, 2);
        close(fd_logfile);
    }
    
    /* ... */
    fprintf(stderr, "This should go to logfile.txt\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the useful idea Sir. but I have a small question here: why need to close the fd_logfile just right after duplicate it. Why not somewhere else or other function?

Comment: @ahtong: After calling `dup2` you have to file descriptors pointing the the same file. The one originally opened `fd_logfile` and `2`. You only need one of them to be open (`2`); the other one is redundant and can (and should) be closed immediately after `dup2`-ing it.